# O último privilégio não está traduzido

Tags: bug, tradução

O privilégio `access to site analytics`, [assim como a página explicatória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) não estão traduzidas.

Tradução sugeridas:

**access to site analytics** - Acesso aos dados do site

**access to internal and Google site analytics** - Acesso aos dados internos e relatórios dosite do Google

Para a página de explicação:

> **O que são os dados do site?**
>
> As pessoas que administram sites usam dados sobre como o site é usado
>   para tomar decisões informadas. Uma vez que os nossos sites são
>   geridos pela comunidade nós damos, aos utilizadores mais empenhados,
>   acesso especial a alguns dados obtidos.
>
> **História**
>
> Três gráficos mostram uma linha do tempo dos posts, votos e tráfico. É
>   possível escolher um intervalo de tempo usando os campos de data
>   presentes no topo da página:
>
> //controlos vão aqui
>
> As datas marco do site também são disponibilizadas, ao clicar nelas os
>   gráficos serão desenhados a partir dessa data. Ao selecionar a
>   *checkbox* "Semanal" agrupará os valores por semana.
>
> É possível seccionar a informação a ser mostrada á esquerda de cada
>   gráfico:
>
> //imagem votes (csv) vem aqui
>
> Obtenha uma cópia
>   [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) dos dados
>   mostrados para que possa analisá-los *offline*, clicando no *link* "csv".
>   Note que ao contrário das restantes fontes, como o SEDE, é
>   disponibilizada informacao sobre os *posts* apagados.
>
> **Google Analytics**
>
> Esta aba dá-lhe acesso para selecionar informacao do Google Analytics
>   dos últimos 30 dias. Existem  umas pequenas gralhas nos dados:
>
> - DuckDuckGo remete para o site e não aparece como ferramenta de busca.
> - É feita uma amostragem dos números e possível ver resultados implausíveis, tais como várias ferramentas de busca com 211 visitas
> - Nós temos uma quota de API limitada, por isso intervalos de tempo arbitrários não são suportados
> - Termos de busca não são confiáveis e por isso não os mostramos
>
> **Como posso usar estes dados?**
>
> Uma vez que este é um privilégio restrito, nós preferíamos que não
>   partilhasse os dados. Contudo, esperamos que você partilhe a sua
>   análise com outros utilizadores no meta. Por exemplo, sites maduros do
>   Stack Exchange obtém a maior parte do seu tráfico a partir de
>   ferramentas de busca (especialmente o Google). Partilhar a percentagem
>   do tráfego pode revelar alguns pontos fortes e fracos do site.
>
> Não se sinta obrigado a partilhar os dados. (E se ainda não tiver o
>   privilegio não pressione aqueles que têm a partilhar). É sobretudo uma
>   forma de satisfazer a sua curiosidade sobre o estado da comunidade.

Esta é apenas uma tradução sugerida, aconselho que raleiem o texto e façam ajustes necessários.

Comment: Já foi reportado  aqui: [**Traduções de páginas e links da “Central de Ajuda”**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5316/28595)